# Why is blockquote element not inheriting parent p's styles?

Tags: html, css

I have very very simple HTML:

```
<p>
<blockquote>
</blockquote
</p>
```

The `p` element has a rule in an external stylesheet to define the font-family and color, yet when the `blockquote` is inside the `p`, the `blockquote` is not inheriting any of the `p`'s styles.  This is in IE 9.

Why is this?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You cannot have a blockquote inside a paragraph.

Since the end tag for a paragraph is optional, the following means:

```
<p>            <!-- Start paragraph -->
<blockquote>   <!-- Blockquote forbidden inside p. End paragraph. Start blockquote -->
</blockquote>  <!-- End blockquote -->
</p>           <!-- End paragraph. Paragraph not open. Error. Ignore. -->
```

Comment: Simple, concise, enlightening. Where's the +2 button?